# How to call subfunction in JavascriptCore?

Tags: ios, objective-c, javascriptcore

I'm using `JavascriptCore` in my app, but having some troubles. My javascript is structure like this:

```
var Restaurant = function()
{
    this.street = function()
    {
        return "One Street 45";
    }

    this.postal = function()
    {
        return "90210";
    }
}
```

Now, in Javascript I created a function that allows for a restaurant to add itself to the map:

```
addMeToTheMap(Restaurant);
```

And in the `JSContext` this maps to:

```
self.context[@"addMeToTheMap"] = ^(JSValue *restaurant) {
};
```

What I find difficult though is to be able to call the `street` and `postal` functions. I tried doing `[[restaurant callWithArguments:nil] @"street"] callWithArguments:nil]`, but that didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you creating the reference to `restaurant`?

Comment: I'm not. The `Restaurant` variable in the javascript can have any name.

Comment: Right, what I mean is are you doing: `JSValue *restaurant = self.context[@"Restaurant"]`?

Comment: I'm getting the value from the `addMeToTheMap()` function, so would there be a need to do that?

Answer (score 0):

**Why**

Think about what you're logically saying in `[[restaurant callWithArguments:nil] @"street"] callWithArguments:nil]`.

You don't have a return statement in the restaurant function in JavaScript. So `[restaurant callWithArguments:nil]` will return void.

Also `street` and `postal` both return strings. Not `this`, therefore `[[... @"street"] callWithArguments:nil]` is trying to call a string as a function. Not to mention this shouldn't even compile because of `[... @"some string"]`.

**What you actually want**

What you want to do is use the `objectForKeyedSubscript:` method on `JSValue` which returns a `JSValue`. So instead of using `callWithArgs`. You should do something like:

```
[restaurant[@"street" <or> @"postal"] callWithArguments:nil]
```

Which will return your string wrapped in a `JSValue`. Which you can unwrap using `toString`.

Comment: Well, if I do that it returns `(null)`. This is what I changed it to: `self.context[@"addMeToTheMap"] = ^(JSValue *restaurant) {
            NSLog(@"street: %@", [restaurant[@"street"] callWithArguments:nil]);
        };`

Comment: Can you log at `restaurant` and `restaurant[@"street"] `?